# How to pass an array to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Code:

```
void case1();
void case2();
void case3();
void case4();
void case5();

//Global variables
const int MAXROW = 5;
const int MAXCOL = 5;

int main()
{
    ........
    ...
MENU(with do while)
}

void case1()
{
    int A[MAXROW][MAXCOL] = { 0 };

    for (int r = 0; r < MAXROW; ++r)
        for (int c = 0; c < MAXCOL; ++c) {
            cout << "\n A[" << r << "][" << c << "]= ";
            cin >> A[r][c];
        }
}

void case2()
{
    ...
}

//Function to find average of negatives
void case3()
{
    int negNumber = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < 6; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 6; ++c) {
            if...
}

void case4()
{//Function to find product of numbers different from 0
    ...
}

void case5()
{
    ...
}
```

As you can see the input array is in `case1()`. What I wonder is how to use this array in all other functions (`case2`, `case3`, `case4`, `case5`).

How can I do this?

How to call them in the menu? For example `case2()`:

```
case '2': {
    case2(......);
```

For now my error list is full of messages like

> 'A': undeclared identifier

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: You got it slightly shorter by dropping complete completely, but are still not that much nearer to minimal. I suggest you delete it, take some time reformulating (and rebuilding your example), and only when you are ready undelete and edit it. (As-is, you'll just collect down- and close-votes...)

Comment: Any arrays defined locally in functions can't be seen inside other functions. As you're asking you need to define that array at global scope (not that I consider this a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array by reference, for example:

```
void case1(int (&A)[MAXROW][MAXCOL])
{
  // do use array here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your array in the `main` function, *not* in one of your `case...` functions. In C++, objects (including arrays) are destroyed once the execution passes out of the block in which the object is defined. So in your code

```
void case1()
{
    int A[MAXROW][MAXCOL] = { 0 };
    ...
}
```

once the execution leaves the function `case1`, the array `A` is destroyed. The compiler tries to tell you this, when it complains about unknown name `A`. This is not what you want! Instead, do this:

```
int main()
{
    int A[MAXROW][MAXCOL] = { 0 };
    ...
    // your menu code
    ...
    switch (menu_result)
    {
    case 1: case1(A); break;
    case 2: case2(A); break;
    case 3: case3(A); break;
    case 4: case4(A); break;
    case 5: case5(A); break;
    }
}
```

Here, you are passing the array `A` to your functions. In order to make this code work, you should declare that your functions receive the array as a parameter:

```
void case1(int (&A)[MAXROW][MAXCOL])
{
  // do use array here
}
```

(code taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617613/509868) answer)

---

BTW the pass-by-reference syntax is rarely used for arrays, because the code works even if you omit the reference sign `&`:

```
void case2(int A[MAXROW][MAXCOL]) // also works; does the same
{
}
```

In this case, you can also omit the outer dimension of the array:

```
void case3(int A[][MAXCOL]) // also works; does the same
{
}
```

The reason these two variants also work [is a bit technical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/509868) - in these variants, the thing being passed is a pointer to a one-dimensional array, not a reference to a two-dimensional array. I wanted to avoid mentioning them, but it's not really possible, because they are widely used (possibly because they can be compiled by a C compiler).

Comment: Yes with this the errors in one case1 disappear but how to do it in the another fucntion. [code]void case1(int (&A)[MAXROW][MAXCOL])[/code] It is the same as case 1?

Comment: or something like this void case2(int A[][])

Comment: or this : void case2 ( int A[MAXROW][MAXCOL])

Comment: Yes, i tryed  this but their is new error : 
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl case3(int (* const)[5])" (?case3@@YAXQAY04H@Z) referenced in function _main.

Comment: And I cant undestand why this is only for case 3,4,5

Comment: This is unrelated to your question. Ask a different question for that, or solve that problem by yourself (should be easy).

Comment: Can be casue by the reference, maybe case3 doesn use the A? The fuction use newarr.